# Converting Multipolygon to Polygon and saving in new table in Oracle Spatial?

Tags: sql, oracle-spatial

I have a data set with mixed SDO_GTYPE 2007 and SDO_GTYPE 2003, however for the task I am working on only SDO_GTYPE 2003 is allowed for practical reasons.

I was able to extract the polygons in a querie from the multipolygons, however I don't know how to save the polygons in a new table and I couldn't find any helpful information on how to do it.

My code so far:

```
SELECT SDO_UTIL.EXTRACT_ALL(t1.GEOMETRY, 0)
FROM table t1
WHERE t1.GEOMETRY.SDO_GTYPE = 2007;

CREATE TABLE "TEST"."POLYGON" 
   (    "GEOINVFL_N" VARCHAR2(16 CHAR), 
    "GEOMETRY" "MDSYS"."SDO_GEOMETRY" 
   )
```

I am working in Oracle 12.1

Comment: Are your gtype=2007 multipolygons real, multipart multipolygons? And is your aim to split the multipolygon into many singlepart polygons with the same attributes as the original multipolygon?

Comment: Yes they are real multipart polygons and yes, I want to keep the original attributes. Thanks for your interest!

Comment: This is not really a spatial question but rather an Oracle SQL question regarding array manipulation.  Your use of SDO_UTIL.EXTRACT_ALL will convert your multipolygon into an array of polygon geometries - all good.  You have the spatial part of the matter down pat.  Well then you need to loop through your array one-by-one and insert the polygons one-by-one into new rows in your table.  There are a variety of ways to do this as as the solution needs to know your schema - there is no simple one size fits all procedure.  I usually use an Oracle pipelined function for this purpose.  Out of space

Comment: Pipelined functions in the old days needed a custom type to model the output but now 18c has the nifty ROW POLYMORPHIC clause to perhaps avoid all that (not going to help you I guess).  Perhaps a lot easier is just an anonymous block that reads your table rows one-by-one doing a single insert for each row but "stuttering" when necessary to generate a unique row for each component polygon.  You would probably want to adjust your primary key during this process, no?  I think I am driving at this not being a quick solution, it needs some logic to make work. Cheers, Paul

Comment: @pauldzy thanks for your thoughts, I too realize this is not going to be a quick solution ;)